# Login as Service Principal Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell empty list

Tags: azure, powershell, powerapps, power-platform

I am logging into the PowerApps Administration PowerShell cmdlets with the next command:

`Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint prod -TenantID $tenantId -ApplicationId $appId -ClientSecret $secret -Verbose`

That service principal has already been added to the Power Platform Admin Default Environment with the System Administrator Security Role, and also, in the Azure Portal > App Registration > API Permissions, added the Dynamics CRM > user_impersonation permission, and still cannot retrieve the environments/apps/etc. `Get-AdminPowerAppEnvironment` gets nothing.

What do you think I am missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it work if you attempt to fetch a specific environment? eg. `Get-AdminPowerAppEnvironment -Default` or `Get-AdminPowerAppEnvironment -Name "nameOfEnvYouExpectToHaveAdminAccessTo"`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it brings empty parameters but in the Internal field says this ; Error=; Message=The service principal with id XXXX for application XXXX does not have permission to access the path 'https://europe.api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.Busines
sAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments/~default?$expand=permissions&api-version=2016-11-01' in tenant XXX.; Internal=StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, (I changed the UIDs with XXXX for security reasons) but looks like I must give more permissions to the service principal besides System Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Is it added as an application user through the yoururl.crmx.dynamics.com/aspx?settingsonly=true or through the modern way from the admin settings?

It has to be specified as application user, just adding as user won't work.

Comment: I added it as an application user but in the Power Platform admin center. Not in the CRM Dynamics portal. Shouldn't that be enough? What do you suggest?

Comment: Are you using Windows Server? There is a known issue with that.

But next to that, did you run Windows PowerShell ISE in Admin mode?

Comment: Not using windows server, I am using Windows 10 Home, PowerShell 7, in administrator mode.